# Guzzle making a GET request instead of POST

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I'm sure this is going to be marked as a duplicate, but I've looked through all the given questions on the same subject and tried many of the suggested solutions, and they haven't worked.

I'm in a laravel project and I have a post request going out through guzzle.

```
           $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
           $response = $client->request('POST', $url, [
                'headers' => [
                    'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $apiToken,
                    'Accept' => 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                    'allow_redirects' => false,
                    // 'allow_redirects'=>['strict'=>true]
                ],
                'json' => json_decode($logText, true)
            ]);
```

I keep on getting the response back `"message": "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."`

I've checked and indeed, it's sending a GET request to the same `$url` specified above.

I didn't have those `allow_redirects` settings at first, but both settings were offered up as potential solutions when I googled around. Unfortunately, both options result in the same error message: `The GET method is not supported for this route.`

Why in the world is my POST request changing to a GET request?

I've also tried `$client->post` instead, and THAT became a GET request as well.

I've also double checked that the GET error message isn't actually coming from inside the POST request: it's not. The POST route isn't being hit at all.

PHP version `7.2`, Laravel version `6.0.2`, Guzzle version `6.5.3`

Comment: Make sure you don't have any redirects set up on the server, such as HTTP -> HTTPS.

Comment: Dude. I've been banging my head against a wall for hours. That's exactly what it was. HTTP -> HTTPS. Go ahead and post this as an answer, i'll mark it as correct. For some reason none of the existing answers on the internet said this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check for redirects on the server, such as HTTP -> HTTPS. Redirects are always a GET request, which will mess up non-GET routing. Using the correct protocol all the way through (such as always use HTTPS) will bypass the redirect.

Comment: weird that when i explicitly put `'allow_redirects' => false`, it still does this redirect. But that's what it was -> http to https. Thanks

Comment: I think it's in the wrong spot. allow_redirects is an option, not a header, so it should have been placed on the same level as headers and json.

Comment: of course! duh, i wasn't paying much attention to detail there. I never thought it was a header, but i stupidly put it in that array anyway.